# The equation $x \sinh y + y \cosh x =e^x$ defines $y$ as a function of $x$ near $(x,y)=(1,1)$. Find $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ at $x = 1$.

Tags: calculus

Ok, so I take the derivative and I get
$$
x \cosh yy' + \sinh y + y \sinh x + \cosh xy' = e^x,
$$
then I isolate for $y'$ and I get $\displaystyle y' = \frac{e^x - y \sinh x - \sinh y}{x \cosh y + \cosh x}$, but I do not know where to go from there..

Thanks

Comment: Implicit function theorem.

Comment: I have to believe that your textbook has an example of doing just this.  You already did all the hard work, even!

Comment: **Hint:**    $y(1)=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were told that $y=1$ when $x=1$, so just evaluate $y'$ at $x=1,y=1$:

$$
{dy\over dx}{\Huge|}_{x=1,y=1}={e^1-1\cdot\sinh 1-\sinh 1\over 1\cdot\cosh 1+\cosh 1}={e-2\sinh 1\over 2\cosh 1}.
$$

Comment: Thanks homie, appreciate that!